# How can I set runtime variable for docker compose environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am creating a docker compose file which requires some environment variables. One of the env var is from aws ssm parameter. So I need to query the value from aws ssm when I build the docker image and put the value as one of the environment variable. How can I do that in docker compose file?

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PYTHON_ENV=developmen
        - API_KEY= # find the value from ssm
```

Comment: Is your Dockerfile defined with `API_KEY`, You can set the varibale only when your Docker container contains the variable. Then FOllow my answer to define in docker-compose and .env file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861914/load-environment-variables-from-env-file-with-docker-and-php/57873096#57873096#answer-57873096

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no easy way to process `ARGs` in docker-compose file from a subshell. But you can do this with `docker build` command and docker-compose with key-value.

using the docker-compose command:

```
MY_KEY=$(aws  ssm get-parameter --name "test" --output text --query Parameter.Value) docker-compose build --no-cache
```

docker-compose

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PYTHON_ENV=developmen
        - API_KEY=${MY_KEY}
```

Define ARGs in Dockerfile and run subshell during build time to get the SSM parameter value.

```
FROM alpine
ARG API_KEY=default
ENV API_KEY="$API_KEY"
RUN echo  "API_KEY is : $API_KEY"
```

During build get the value using `aws-cli`

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg API_KEY="$(aws  ssm get-parameter --name "test" --output text --query Parameter.Value)" -t myimage .
```

With docker-compose you can also try with system environment variable.

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PYTHON_ENV=developmen
        - API_KEY=${MY_KEY}
```

Export it as an ENV before docker-compose.

```
 export MY_KEY=$(aws  ssm get-parameter --name "test" --output text --query Parameter.Value) && docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Comment: This solutions is best than use awscli inside docker build to get the ssm parameter? Very nice explanation! Thanks!

Comment: Actually no, this is storing sensitive information in the dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to run script/code inside docker-compose file. So, you have to run the dynamic api key generation script outside the docker-compose file.

Anyway, you can declare a variable like `API_KEY_FROM_SSM` in docker-compose file

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PYTHON_ENV=developmen
        - API_KEY=${API_KEY_FROM_SSM}
```

and query the value from aws ssm and assign it to `API_KEY_FROM_SSM` when you build image.

```
API_KEY_FROM_SSM=$(your aws ssm script) docker-compose build
```

Hope, it helps.