# AWS Parameter Store inside docker-compose.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-parameter-store

I save all secret data into AWS Parameter Store, my app run with docker-compose and I try to evaluate `aws ssm get-parameters` just inside `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name DB_USERNAME --region eu-north-1 --output text --query Parameters[].Value)
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name DB_PASSWORD --region eu-north-1 --output text --with-decryption --query Parameters[].Value)
      POSTGRES_DB: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name DB_NAME --region eu-north-1 --output text --query Parameters[].Value)
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  auth:
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_ENDPOINT: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name DB_ENDPOINT --region eu-north-1 --output text --query Parameters[].Value)
      DB_USERNAME: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name DB_USERNAME --region eu-north-1 --output text --query Parameters[].Value)
      DB_PASSWORD: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name DB_PASSWORD --region eu-north-1 --output text --with-decryption --query Parameters[].Value)
      JWT_KEY: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name JWT_KEY --region eu-north-1 --output text --query Parameters[].Value)
      JWT_EXPIRED: $$(aws ssm get-parameters --name JWT_EXPIRED --region eu-north-1 --output text --query Parameters[].Value)
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

But construction `$$(<command>)` doesn't work.

Instead of expected values from the parameter store, I'm getting

> $(get-parameters --name DB_ENDPOINT --region eu-north-1 --output text
> --query Parameters[].Value)

I know how to do this with prepare a script like `export MY_VAR="$(get-parameters ...)"` that is understood.

But the question is can I fetch Parameter Store values just in `docker-compose.yaml` if yes, how?

Comment: may be this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57881364/6515755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunally there's no way to do this.

As you said, you have to set the environment variable before running command `docker-compose up`:

```bash
export MY_KEY=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "YOUR-PARAMETER-NAME" [--with-decryption] --output text --query Parameter.Value)
```

and then in your `docker-compose.yml` file, set the environment variable:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  ...
    environment:
      MY_SSM_KEY: ${MY_KEY}
  ...
```

Now, `docker-compose up` will run as desired.